# 403 error Flask - Debian 9

Tags: python, linux, nginx, debian, flask

Пытаюсь поднять Flask на домене http://domain_name.ru/ , на данный момент домен отдает 403 код ответа.
При заходе по IP с портом 5000, все норм, домен отображается.

При проверке sudo nginx -t ошибок нет, но сайт не доступен.
**Вопрос, мне инклюды для самого домена в настройках nginx нужно прописывать или нет?**
я использовал [эту инструкцию](https://digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04)

**При запросе sudo systemctl status:**

```
 State: degraded
 Jobs: 0 queued
 Failed: 1 units
 Since: Fri 2020-04-24 15:15:22 MSK; 1 day 16h ago
```

**При запросе sudo nginx -t**

```
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

**В основных настройках nginx я указал, что данные нужно брать из папки sites-available и прописал инклюд:**

```
include         /etc/nginx/sites-available/*;
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/vhosts/*/*.conf;
```

**В конфиге nginx для домена у меня не прописан инклюд:**

```
include         /etc/nginx/sites-available/*;
```

Настройки Гуникорна:
**Вопрос тут путь нужно указывать полный вплоть до папки с приложением или?**

```
[Service]
User=user_sanitarn
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/user_sanitarn/myproject
Environment="PATH=/home/user_sanitarn/myproject/myprojectenv/bin"
ExecStart=/home/user_sanitarn/myproject/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:myproject.sock -m 007 wsgi:app
```

**При запросе sudo systemctl status myproject**
●

```
 myproject.service - Gunicorn instance to serve myproject
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/myproject.service; enabled; vendor preset
: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2020-04-25 13:36:43 MSK; 18h ag
o
 Main PID: 20343 (gunicorn)
   CGroup: /system.slice/myproject.service
           ├─20343 /var/www/novikov/data/www/my_domain.ru/myprojectenv/bin/python                                                     3.
5 /var/www/novikov/data/www/my_domain.ru/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --
bind unix:myproject.sock -m 007 wsgi:app
           ├─20345 /var/www/novikov/data/www/my_domain.ru/myprojectenv/bin/python                                                     3.
5 /var/www/novikov/data/www/my_domain.ru/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --
bind unix:myproject.sock -m 007 wsgi:app
           ├─20346 /var/www/novikov/data/www/my_domain.ru/myprojectenv/bin/python                                                     3.
5 /var/www/novikov/data/www/my_domain.ru/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --
bind unix:myproject.sock -m 007 wsgi:app
           └─20347 /var/www/novikov/data/www/my_domain.ru/myprojectenv/bin/python                                                     3.
5 /var/www/novikov/data/www/my_domain.ru/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --
bind unix:myproject.sock -m 007 wsgi:app

Apr 25 13:36:43 finans systemd[1]: Started Gunicorn instance to serve mypr
oject.
Apr 25 13:36:43 finans gunicorn[20343]: [2020-04-25 13:36:43 +0300] [20343
] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
Apr 25 13:36:43 finans gunicorn[20343]: [2020-04-25 13:36:43 +0300] [20343] [INFO] Listening at: unix:myproject.sock (20343)
Apr 25 13:36:43 finans gunicorn[20343]: [2020-04-25 13:36:43 +0300] [20343] [INFO] Using worker: sync
Apr 25 13:36:43 finans gunicorn[20343]: [2020-04-25 13:36:43 +0300] [20345] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 20345
Apr 25 13:36:43 finans gunicorn[20343]: [2020-04-25 13:36:43 +0300] [20346] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 20346
Apr 25 13:36:43 finans gunicorn[20343]: [2020-04-25 13:36:43 +0300] [20347] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 20347
Apr 25 13:39:00 finans systemd[1]: myproject.service: Failed to set invocation ID on control group /system.slice/myproj
ect.service, ignoring: Operation not permitted
Warning: myproject.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.
novikov@finans:~$
```

Как еще можно отловить  ошибки, чтобы запустить приложение?
Уже не первый день пытаюсь запустить, надеюсь на помощь. Спасибо!

Comment: Ну раз по порту работает, пропишите в конфиге nginx для домена прокси на порт, тогда всё заработает с домена...

Comment: @VladimirGonchar
Все вроде бы прописано , вот конфиг домена nginx:
http://prntscr.com/s77e5p

Вот конфиг самого nginx:
http://prntscr.com/s77f79

Ограничения по символам не дают разместить код.

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему, пришлось много времени на nginx потратить.
Так вот, по инструкции выше, создается конфиг для голого nginx, то есть по умолчанию, а так как у меня домен привязывался через панель ISP Manager, то там был свой конфиг, вот этот данный конфиг нужно было поправить и изменить строки в location, заменив имеющиеся на:

```
include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/ПОЛНЫЙ путь до/myproject.sock;
```

В общем проблема в 2х строках, а времени было убито мною море.
Надеюсь, кому то поможет мой ответ.

Comment: так 403 ошибка говорит что какой-то косяк с прокси:)

Comment: Эх, такой халявный конкурс проспал :)